# installing grass71 on centos6

Tags: grass-gis, installation, centos

I am installing grass71 on centos6 , i have the following message after running grass71

```
[bachir@nexus ~]$ grass71
Starting GRASS GIS...
g.gisenv: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/lib/libgrass_gis.7.1.svn.so)
g.gisenv: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/lib/libgrass_datetime.7.1.svn.so)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/gui/wxpython/gis_set.py", line 31, in <module>
    from core import globalvar
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 29, in <module>
    from core.debug import Debug
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 72, in <module>
    Debug = DebugMsg()
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.SetLevel()
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/gui/wxpython/core/debug.py", line 43, in SetLevel
    self.debuglevel = int(grass.gisenv().get('WX_DEBUG', 0))
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 952, in gisenv
    s = read_command("g.gisenv", flags='n')
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 458, in read_command
    process = pipe_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 433, in pipe_command
    return start_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 372, in start_command
    if debug_level() > 0:
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 1535, in debug_level
    _debug_level = int(gisenv().get('DEBUG', 0))
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 952, in gisenv
    s = read_command("g.gisenv", flags='n')
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 461, in read_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, stdout, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/grass7.1.svn-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-08_02_2016/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 329, in handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None [b'g.gisenv', b'-n'] ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the (error) output.
ERROR: Error in GUI startup. See messages above (if any) and if necessary, please report this error to the GRASS developers.
On systems with package manager, make sure you have the right GUI package, probably named grass-gui, installed.
To run GRASS GIS in text mode use the -text flag.
Exiting...
[bachir@nexus ~]$ uname -a
Linux nexus 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 15 21:19:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the GLIBC version installed on your system? This post may help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5